# upon reading QRCode in swift, failing to load a new View Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, qr-code, viewcontroller

I am trying to build an app that has 3 View Controllers
1. HomeViewController -> A Button that navigates to the second View(ScannerViewController)
2. ScannerViewController -> This will read the QRCode. I have used the code found at https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code

Upon call of dismissViewControllerAnimated the HomeViewController gets called. 
Is there a way to load the third View Controller(InfoViewController) that I have.

I tried loading the InfoViewController from the viewdidappear method of HomeViewController, but I get the warning "*Warning: Attempt to present qrcode.InfoViewController: 0x14ed29d90 on qrcode.HomeViewController: 0x14ee98bf0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!*"

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the code at location https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code    , why don't you remove the line dismissViewControllerAnimated and in place load the infoViewController.
 First get the infoviewcontroller at that place . `infoVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("infoviewcontrollerid") as? infoViewController`
 i.e. your class name in place of infoViewController and than you present your view controller like this

```
 self.presentViewController(infoVC, animated: Bool) { nil }
```